# Block my website on Android apps

Tags: javascript, java, android

As you know, there are many sites that create Android apps for websites just by adding the link

What if someone created a application for your website and Published it on Google Play without your knowledge

Is there a JavaScript code that prevents my website from appearing on Android applications?
And your opinion on that
Thank you

Comment: THis isn't a technical issue, its a legal one.  Issue a DMCA takedown request for violating your copyright.

Comment: @GabeSechan depends on the country/countries in question. DMCA looks like it only applies to the US.

Answer (score 1):

Simple.

You can't.

iframes makes other websites able to use your website, and using a webview allows it in an Android app. if you were to block webviews, it wouldn't be visible in chrome on Android.

You cannot block android apps from displaying your website. And you cannot block ios apps from displaying your website. You can detect if the website is included in an iframe, and you could block it like that. But this would limit it to external pages showing your page.

---

And allow me to explain why it would be a terrible idea to block android apps from viewing your site:

- The app would use Webview
- The webview either connects to your site or a different site with your site as an iframe
- If you somehow could block the webview, you would also block **all android browsers** from viewing your website.

Alternatively, one could use a BufferedReader or somethign else to get the entire site source code, and then display it in the app. I think you can supply HTML code to a webview and it gets rendered

---

This is slightly misinterpreting your statement (on purpose though):

> What if someone created a application for your website and Published it on Google Play without your knowledge

How about Google Chrome?

If your site is wordpress, the wordpress app.

And if I today created a browser, would I have to notify every website that it may display their content?

You are on the internet, the open access sites (not password restricted) can be displayed all over the internet. Unless your site is **extremely popular** no one will actually bother creating an app for it. There are probably apps displaying Google, but those will not get taken down unless the creator:

- Pretends to be Google
- Pretends the app is official
- Tries to sell Google as his/her creation

because that goes under copyright. However, as long as it is disclosed that the website displayed is not the app poster's creation, but the app is there as a utility to make accessing the website easier than it currently is.

---

**EDIT:**

This now turns into a legal question. Therefore, I would like to give tips on what you can do.

You can flag the app. [Intellectual property deception](https://play.google.com/intl/en_ALL/about/ip-deception-spam/impersonation-ip/unauthorized-copyright/) is mentioned in the google play developer policy. Or as Gabe Sechan suggested, issue a DMCA takedown.

I'm not a lawyer, so I'm not sure how you would do the second, or other ways to handle this. You could ask this question on [law.stackexchange.com](https://law.stackexchange.com/) and you would probably get some good responses.

Comment: You can detect if your page is included in an iframe, so that argument is not valid here.

Comment: I don't do a lot of webdev, so I was not aware of that. WIll remove that part

Comment: One of them exploits my website at Google Play without my consent

Comment: He created an Android app for my website and Published  on Google Play and put the ads too

Comment: That would be against the Google Play developer policy. You can flag the app. It goes under: https://play.google.com/intl/en_ALL/about/ip-deception-spam/impersonation-ip/unauthorized-copyright/ . It is probably against the law in your country too (no clue what country that is, so can't confirm nor deny). If it is against the law, the question lies in how you would find the person and file the charge. For now, you can get the app removed from Google Play. (Don't take any of this as legal advice, I'm not a lawyer.)

Comment: It is copyright infringement, monetising on your intellectual property.

Comment: As for fighting it, I guess you could put a warning banner about the app (even link to it) and tell the users that that app isn't official. Or add a banner telling them about an official app (you would have to create one of course)

Comment: Thank you very much  LunarWatcher for your information
The funny thing is that a warning appears when you install the application
"This app may be harmful to your phone or data"